# Regex to pull out name

Tags: r

I have a ragged list of place names e.g.

```
                                  place
        District1 / Commune2 / Village3
                    Region1 / District2
District3 / Commune1 / Village1 / Farm1
```

So we have place names at different levels of resolution. I want to extract the last name for geocoding purposes e.g.

```
    place
 Village3
District2
    Farm1
```

Can somebody show me a regular expression that searches for the last "/" and then keeps only place name after this? Many thanks. What confuses me are the escape characters in R regex queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace everything `".*"` up to and including the last slash and space `"/ "` with the empty string:

```
gsub(".*/ ", "", DF$place)
## [1] "Village3"  "District2" "Farm1"
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "
                                  place
        District1 / Commune2 / Village3
                    Region1 / District2
District3 / Commune1 / Village1 / Farm1"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE, sep = ";")
```

Comment: Some farms have the same name. The Google Maps API needs more information to give a more accurate geo-location. Adding village name and farm name may be necessary. Have to think how to expand gsub expression to use both names.

Answer (score 1):

This also works:

```
trimws(basename(df$place))
```